# Store classes in a Map so that they can be instantiated

Tags: java, class, oop, dictionary, first-class

I want to be able to create instances of classes, based on `HashMap` entries.

E.g. this is what I'd try writing off the top of my head:

```
public class One implements Interface {
  public void sayName() {
    System.out.println("One");
  }
}

public class Two implements Interface {
  public void sayName() {
    System.out.println("Two");
  }
}

Map<String, Interface> associations = new HashMap<String, Interface>();

associations.put("first", One);
associations.put("second", Two);

Interface instance = new associations.get("first")();

instance.sayName(); // outputs "One"
```

But I strongly suspect this will not work in Java.

---

My situation: I want to create a way to associate `String` names with classes.

A user can create instances of a class by using its "name".

I feel like trying: making a map of names to classes (I don't know how to store classes in a map), and getting the item from the map that matches "name" and then instantiating it.

That won't work.

---

How can I associate classes with `String` names and instantiate those classes using the 'name' I've given it?

Comment: You will want to look into the Java reflection API. There's a class.forName method in particular

Comment: Make your map `Map<String, Supplier>` and put `One::new` and `Two::new` instead of `One` or `Two`. Then you can do `associations.get("first").get()`.

Comment: Furthermore, you actually do not want to store classes, but constructors. From a certain point of view, a constructor is just a [Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), i.e. a function that generates something when called. As @Kon said, this most certainly will involve some reflection. You may also want to look at the [Factory method-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and/or [Builder-Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: Your map typing is wrong.  it should be Map<String, String> for the Class.forName approach.  Or else Map<String, Class<? extends Interface>> (and @lexicore has even better suggestion)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) functional interface and a method reference to the default constructor:

```
Map<String, Supplier<Interface>> associations = new HashMap<>();

associations.put("first", One::new);
associations.put("second", Two::new);
```

To instantiate a new object, call [`Supplier.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html#get--):

```
Interface foo = associations.get("first").get();
```

---

If your constructors require arguments, you'll need to use another [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html). For one- and two-argument constructors, you can use [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) and [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) respectively. Any more and you'll need to define your own functional interface. Supposing the constructors both take a string, you could do this:

```
class One implements Interface
{
    One(String foo){ }

    public void sayName() {
        System.out.println("One");
    }
}

Map<String, Function<String, Interface>> associations = new HashMap<>();
associations.put("first", One::new);
```

and then use [`Function.apply`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#apply-T-) to get the instance:

```
Interface a = associations.get("first").apply("some string");
```

If your constructors take different number of arguments then you're out of luck.

Comment: I need to make a function that accepts the "constructors" (`One::new` and `Two::new`), what's the type signature of `Class::new`?

Comment: It doesn't have a type. It will match any functional interface which takes the same number of arguments and returns an `Interface`.

Comment: I need to make a function that wraps the `associations.put`, this function takes the `String` key and the `Class::new` value. The function will look like `void addAssoc(String name, XXX constructor)`. Is `XXX` going to be `Function<String, Interface>` ?

Comment: If the constructors both take 1 string then yes.

Answer (score 3):

I'd highly recommend the use of `Supplier` in [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49697278/7294647).  Alternatively, you should be able to use the following:

```
var associations = Map.of("first", One.class, "second", Two.class);

var foo = associations.get("first").getConstructor().newInstance();
```

If your constructors require arguments, just pass the classes to `getConstructor` and the values to `newInstance`.  For example, if `Two` takes an `int` in its constructor:

```
var foo = associations.get("two").getConstructor(int.class).newInstance(5);
```

**Note**: This uses Java 10.

Comment: after getting from the map how do I pass an argument to the constructor?

Comment: I did see, why are you using the `var` keyword? Is the last `foo` of type `Two`?

Comment: I've not seen this `Map.of` notation before, how do I add single elements to it at a time? (When it's created I don't know how many elements will be in it)

Comment: Yes, I used `var` just to shorten the code (as it's a new feature in Java 10).  I'm not a fan of having to type `Map<String, Class<Interface>>`.  `Map#of` was introduced in Java 9.  To add elements one-by-one, simply initialize a `HashMap` and `put` entries in.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to store classes and create new instances on demand, or store instances and just use them?

```
public class ClassInHashMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,Class<? extends SomeInterface>> associations = new HashMap<String,Class<? extends SomeInterface>>();
        associations.put("first", One.class);
        associations.put("second", Two.class);

        try {
            Class<? extends SomeInterface> someCls = associations.get("first");
            SomeInterface instance = someCls.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            instance.sayName(); // outputs "One"
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

interface SomeInterface {
    public void sayName();
}

class One implements SomeInterface {
    public void sayName() {
        System.out.println("One");
    }
}

class Two implements SomeInterface {
    public void sayName() {
        System.out.println("Two");
    }
}
```